# Prove$ (2^n+3^n) ^{1/n}$ is a decreasing sequence

Tags: proof-writing

We want to prove this without using any calculus.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question?


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111827/question-of-monotone-convergent-sequence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question of monotone convergent sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111827/question-of-monotone-convergent-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(2^x+3^x)^{1/x}=3[1+(2/3)^x]^{1/x}$$
$$\implies \log f(x)= \log 3+\frac{1}{x}\log[1+(2/3)^x]$$
$$\implies f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\log[1+(2/3)^x]+\frac{1}{x}\frac{(2/3)^x \log(2/3)}{1+(2/3)^x}<0$$
Because the first term is negative, the second term is also negative because $\log(2/3)<0.$
Thus $f(x)$ or $f(n), n \in N$ is a decreasing function of $n$.

Comment: Nice proof. I have upvoted it.

Comment: @Angelo Thanks for your appreciation.